# Ensure input name only has alphabets

Tags: python, input

I am trying to input city names to a web scraper. I just want to ensure that the user inputs valid city names which disallows use of any character other than alphabets. Lastly, after the checks are complete, a list of valid city names is returned. Here's what I have been trying

```
def valid_input(i):
    name = i
    while True:
        if not name.isalpha():
            print(f"You have typed {name} incorrectly")
        break

input_string = input("Enter family members separated by comma ")
city_list = input_string.split(',')
for s in city_list:
    try:
        valid_input(s)
    except:
        break
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? There doesn’t seem to be a question here. I would strongly recommend learning more Python, and programming in general, because as it stands there are some aspects of your code which make little sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comment mate. I am a new learner indeed, clearly confused myself so I welcome any constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Your `valid_input` function is a little overly-complicated. It seems like you're lifting a pattern that has to do with asking a user for input until that input passes validation, but uses it to decide whether or not to include some inputs that the user has already given.

```py
def valid_input(s):
    return s.isalpha()  # this is all you need

input_string = input("Enter family member separated by commas: ")
city_list = input_string.split(',')
valid_cities = []
for city in city_list:
    if valid_input(city):
        valid_cities.append(city)


# or
valid_cities = [city for city in city_list if valid_input(city]

# or simply
valid_cities = filter(str.isalpha, city_list)
```

Comment: thanks Adam, very helpful